# Labels with halos become faded and transparent in CMV when using an aerial image

Tags: web-mapping, configurable-map-viewer

I am using [CMV](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app) to create a web map but when I use esri's world imagery or another image service as my base map, my labels (only with halos - Aerial 10pt with 2pt halo) become faded and transparent -  see image below.

I have change the font style, size, colors, halos (note that the labels are fine without halos).

[image: Example of issue]

Comment: How are you adding the label layer? For example, is it an ArcGIS Server Dynamic layer, etc? If it's ArcGIS Server, have you set [anti-aliasing](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/linux/setting-map-service-properties.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_7B8A2893082E46308CC207548C37D800)?

Comment: Published as a map service from ArcGIS to Arcgis Server. The rest end point is then used as a dynamic layer in cmv. Anti-aliasing, no I have not set this. but it is something I could try. Setting this is done in Arc prior to publishing or on the server?

Answer (score 2):

So it turned out if I don't use pure white (255,255,255) but use an off-white (changed by a single value e.g 254,255,255), the labels display fine.